# Return class object after changing object variables

Tags: python, oop

Im new to OOP in Python (and in general) and wondering about the correct way to change object variables. Since Python cant return void i need to return something when an object variable has changed.

```
class classA:
   var_a = 1
   var_b = 1

def changeSomething(classAObj):
    classAObj.var_a = 2
    return classAobj

def main()
    classAObj = classA()
    changeSomething(classAObj)
    .....use object with new changes here....
```

Is it correct to return the entire classAObj in the changeSomething function? Or should i only return the variable i.e

```
...
return classAobj.var_a
```

I get the same result in either way, classAObj.var_a has changed in both cases, but what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: You don't have to return anything from the function. The function modifies `classAObj` in place.

Comment: The correct way is whatever you want your function to do and return as a result.  There is no requirement here.  You don't need a function in this case: `classAObj.var_a = 2` is used to change the variable for the *instance* and `classA.var_a = 2` is used to change the variable for the class itself (like class member in C).

Comment: Python doesn't generally use "fluent interfaces", so you don't normally chain modification functions.

Comment: `Since Python cant return void` what do you mean? It returns `None` if there is no explicit return value. You can define a function's return value type, via its type hint, to be `None`. ` i need to return something when an object variable has changed.` the only "need" to do something like this is when you have designed your program to work that way. But why not return a `bool` indicating if the value changed or not? That seems like the simplest option.

Comment: " i need to return something when an object variable has changed." why do you have to return something? What happens when you wrote no `return` statement?

Comment: @RandomDavis so, void functions in C/++ etc  cannot form part of an expression. Python no such concept. Every python function returns some value, by default, `None`, which is just a conventional, handy, singleton object.

Comment: "Is it correct to return the entire classAObj in the changeSomething function? Or should i only return the variable" neither is more *correct* than the other. It depends on *what you as the designer of the API want to do*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`changeSomething` should not return *anything*; when it modifies the argument in place, it should return nothing (implicitly `None`). Only functions that make new modified *copies* should return them (and leave the argument unmodified).

So your code should just be:

```
class classA:
   def __init__(self):
       self.var_a = 1  # You forget self here
       self.var_b = 1  # You forget self here

def changeSomething(classAObj):
    classAObj.var_a = 2  # Fix name, self wouldn't exist, you received it by a different name

def main():
    classAObj = classA()
    changeSomething(classAObj)  # classAObj is modified in place, so changes seen in caller
    # .....use object with new changes here....
```

Or, given this is a class, it makes sense to have `changeSomething` be an instance method, e.g.:

```
class classA:
   def __init__(self):
       self.var_a = 1  # You forget self here
       self.var_b = 1  # You forget self here

    # Indented to make it a method of the class
    def changeSomething(self):  # Argument renamed to follow standard naming for instance methods
        self.var_a = 2

def main():
    classAObj = classA()
    classAObj.changeSomething()  # Use method call syntax, classAObj still modified in place
    # .....use object with new changes here....
```

Comment: As a side-note: Your names, for both classes and methods/functions, [violate PEP8 style guidance](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles). It should really be `ClassA` and `change_something`; I didn't change it, but if you're going to write Python code with anyone else, sticking to something mostly PEP8 prevents conflicts.

Comment: "should not return anything" this is an opinion, not a fact. It is a convention of the standard library, but you can have different conventions. As long as it is documented, it is fine. You can write a fluent interface if you want to. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: You can, but I wouldn't say it's idiomatic Python. Same way you can violate PEP8 naming conventions, but shouldn't without *very* good reason. But if you want to fit the rest of the language, you try to stick to the conventions the language already obeys. In other languages it's usually not so consistent, so there is no standard, in Python the convention is nigh universal. If you want a fluent interface, it should follow functional style, and return modified copies, not both mutate in-place and return the object.